# JSP - CSS file and JS files aren't loading at all

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I'm unable to load js and css files in JSP file. In desktop it runs as `http://localhost/` but in server it will run as `http://localhost/myapp/`. How can I ensure it works everywhere?

[image]

```
GET http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

In head Head tag I have this..

```
                <script src="/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Edit: I tried the following and it's still not working..

[image]

Edit: even tried the following as suggested in this [article](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/how-to-create-a-spring-boot-web-application-spring-mvc-with-jsp-thymeleaf)

[image]

Comment: It seems the configured docroot folder does not point to path `webapp/WEB-INF/pages`. Either you move both files into the configured docroot folder or you change the url in jsp file.

Comment: which is the docroot folder in this case? index.jsp loads fine from WEB-INF/pages

Comment: Does `http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.min.js` work?  In my eyes the error message is different from existing source code. Are sure that is only one page that uses this include?

Comment: No it doesn't work. BTW I added the css and js to src/main/resources/static/ but it's still not working

Comment: As I wrote in my eyes the error message does not match with your code.

Comment: Updated the error messages. It was old error message. The links looks correct but 404

Comment: What you can do is take a look at root folder of your local server and look how the file structure looks like. It seems an issue with configuration of your project. I think you use a tomcat server

Comment: Seems like my server structure looks like webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/pages, webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib, webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.

I moved the `css` and `js` folder to `src/main/resoucres/static/` and also I had to remove `@EnableMVC` from the `Application.java` and then it started working.

Also I had to add `{pageContext.request.contextPath}` to `index.jsp` otherwise it wouldn't work on the server since the URL would be `http://localhost/myapp/`.

```
<script src="{pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```